# Facing error while calling OnehopEngine SDK Huawei

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

While I am exploring Huawei OneHop engine.

```
HwOneHopSdk.getInstance().registerOneHop()
```

API returns -1 return code(error). I have configured all the basic things, how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call a registration API, the reason could  be maybe EMUI version may not be up-to-date. OneHop Engine requires EMUI 10.1 or later.

Or, check that required permission () has been granted, otherwise, permission verification will fail.

Please Note: Both devices should be  EMUI 10.1 or later and also application must be installed both the ends.